# calculating inductance formula

Tags: capacitor, inductor, capacitance, inductance

what is the formula for caculating  inductance on the basis of

1)No of turns.
2)Diameter of the wire
3)Diameter of the wounded circle. ?

how to calculate the capacitance value in ceramic capacitor ? which is given as 104 or 103 or 102 etc.

Give me the equation or calculation technique....

Comment: Did you Google for inductance formulae? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor#Inductance_formulae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ceramic capacitor values, the first two digits are the value, the third digit is the tens multiplier, in picofarads.

Thus:

> 104 = 10 * 10000 = 100 nF  = 0.1 microfarad
>   102 = 10 * 100   = 1000 pf = 1 nanofarad
>   183 = 18 * 1000  = 18 nF   = 0.018 microfarad

A simple lookup table exists [here](http://www.csgnetwork.com/capcodeinfo.html).

---

For the inductance calculation, the question does not specify whether self-inductance of a coil with an air-core or some other core is required, or mutual inductance of multiple coils. In any case, this [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Self-inductance_of_a_wire_loop) provides calculation methods; On the assumption that a single coil with an air core is under discussion, this formula will serve the purpose.

For a single layer solenoid, or a circular loop, the relevant formulae are listed in the table on that page.